# How to find components within IWorkbenchPart?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm writing a plugin for a poorly-documented Eclipse RCP application and I need to add a listener to what I believe is a `TreeViewer` within a view.  I have access to the `IWorkbenchPart` representing the view, but how can I get the `TreeViewer` it contains?  I'd guess I need a method to return the child components (i.e. something equivalent to AWT's `getComponents()` method), but I see no such method.

Answer (score 0):

If the part contains a `TreeViewer` then it is likely that this viewer been set as the `ISelectionProvider` for the `IWorkbenchSite` containing the view.

Therefore you could try the following using the `IViewPart` reference that you have:

```
IViewPart; // Your reference to the IViewPart instance

ISelectionProvider provider = part.getSite().getSelectionProvider(); //Hopefully the TreeViewer

provider.addSelectionChangedListener(yourListener);
```